# How do I export to the same network drive that we start from using vba in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post at stackoverflow but I appreciate all the help I've received just doing searches. Alas, I'm not able to find an answer to this next question, possibly because I don't know the right words to use.

Here's my dilemma, and then I'll post the code.

In this part of our process:

1. we edit an .xlsx file,
2. then export it as a .csv
3. then save it to the same directory where the .xlsx is located.

We use a shared drive, with two mapped network drives (each mapped drive is for a different set of clients).

I created a macro to see how Excel would code it (see below), but each time we edit the file, the location will change because it's a different job or perhaps a different client.  Here is the macro "closefile".

Macro

```
Sub CloseFile()
'
' CLOSEFILE Macro
' CLOSES THE FILE IN THE SAME LOCATION AS THE XLS...HOPEFULLY
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+I
'
    ChDir _
        **"Z:\@Client Jobs\House\13579\Folder 3"**
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:= _
        **"Z:\@Client Jobs\House\13579\Folder 3\13579.stage.csv"** _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub

End of Macro
```

Any suggestions on how we can export the csv to the same directory that we start from when we edit the .xlsx?

Rico

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Path` gives you the location.  You don't need to use ChDir if you're providing a full path to SaveAs

Comment: Thanks but it saves it to "C:\Users\Rico\Documents"    ChDir _
        ActiveWorkbook.Path
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:= _
        "13579.rick.staging.placards.csv" _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

Comment: You need to use the `Path` from whichever document was originally opened. Like I noted you do *not* need to use ChDir here (and you should be aware ChDir will not even work if your current directory is on C drive and you're trying to change it to a different drive: in that case you'd first need to call `ChDrive`)

Comment: Per Tim's suggestion: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= ThisWorkbook.Path & "\13579.stage.csv"  , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

Comment: @Sorceri: `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\13579.stage.csv"` can give you an error if the file resides in "Z:\" and hence it is a good practice to check if the right most character in the path is "\" or not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.  This code did everything I wanted. I added the "close file" option at the end:

Sub CloseFile()
  With ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs fileName:=Left(.FullName, InStrRev(.FullName, ".")) & "csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
  End With
*ActiveWorkbook.Close False*
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Like Tim mentioned in comments you do not need the `CHDIR`

Is this what you are trying? This will save the csv file to the same folder where the Excel File resides.

```
Sub CloseFile()
    Dim sPath As String, NewFileName As String

    '~~> This will get the path where this excel file resides
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    '~~> Check if the right most character is "\"
    '~~> If not then add it
    If Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

    NewFileName = sPath & "13579.stage.csv"

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting closer. The file was saved as "C:\Users\Rico\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\13579.stage.csv"

Comment: I store my macros in PERSONAL.XLSB

Comment: Which resides in the XLSTART directory

Comment: In the `workbook_open`, put the code, `msgbox thisworkbook.path` save and close the file and reopen it. what message do you get?